# Better Reporting for CruiseControl.NET

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

Is there any way to generate the good error report from Cruise Control?

I like to get the following things in that report.

1. The line number of File that break the build
2. The name of developer who commited that file. (It should not be related to last person who committed because the build might be broken earlier before last person check-in. )

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

this should be doable with a bit of xsl parsing alone :-)

 Needed steps :

1. Create the xsl file (blame.xsl for instance)
   this xsl should look at the <modifications/> node and the <msbuild/> node to get the data.
2. Define a new xslReportBuildPlugin in your webdashboard.config pointing to the
   new xsl file. Something in the likes of :
   <xslReportBuildPlugin description="Blame"
   actionName="BlameBuildReport" xslFileName="xsl\blame.xsl"/>
3. do an iisreset to activate it (just to be sure) and clear your browser cache

   now you should see a Blame in every build report :-)

Comment: Well, take a look at the CCNet source code available on github: https://github.com/ccnet/CruiseControl.NET/tree/master/project/xsl

Answer (score 1):

[Custom report creation information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009983/making-a-custom-report-with-ccnet/4346705#4346705)

[A custom xsl modification to bring the error info up to the top of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422568/how-to-configure-cruise-control-net-to-show-proper-error-in-web-dashboard/3816553#3816553) - this would be helpful in applying the blame

Then if you add in thesteps from Williams' answer you'd have blame information.

Answer (score 0):

1. You do already have the file/line number. CruiseControl.NET provides the detailed MSBuild report, which is nothing but the usual compiler output.
2. This would be only possible with an extension that is specific your the Version Control System. You would have to write such an extension by yourself (but I doubt that it's worth the effort...).

HTH.

Comment: He doesn't specify that he's using MSBuild, but it's pretty much the same for all builders anyway. Cruisecontrol will provide as much details as it is given by the loggers of it's builders.

Comment: Yes.. I'm using MSBuild and I got the line number and etc.. But it's showing.. What I was thinking is that it would be better if I can get the error message, the file name and line of that file that has that error, and person who committed the code.. 

How can I write the extension? I'm using SVN. Could you please give me some links?