# Making a custom report with ccnet

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

So I have my output that I used the merge task to put into ccnet.

Now what I need to do is come up with my own custom xsl and output the data.

Any ideas on where there maybe a tutorial on how to do this?

For example what plugin do I need to use?  Can I create my own?  What does action name do?

```
<xslReportBuildPlugin description="MSBuild Output" actionName="MSBuildOutputBuildPlugin" xslFileName="xsl\msbuild.xsl" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your cruise control folder:

`CruiseControl.NET\webdashboard\xsl`

- Copy any existing xsl (preferably one that is close to what you already want or in a format you like). you could start an xsl file from scratch also.
- edit it to what you want it to be with your own file name.

I copied the msbuild.xsl to BMsBuild.xsl and made my changes.

then in dashboard.config

```
<xslReportBuildPlugin description="BBuildReport" actionName="BBuildReport" xslFileName="xsl\Bmsbuild.xsl"></xslReportBuildPlugin>
```

- Description: what title you want it to have on the webdashboard link
- actionName: a unique name that will be used to generate a URL for that xsl/report
- xslFileName: the path to the xsl usually just xsl[your xsl file name].xsl

That's the easiest way. The file is nearly entirely xsl so there's not really anything special you need to do or know. Except that the xsl is going to target the merged xml file from whatever you have in the publishers xml logger tag in your `ccnet.config`

```
<publishers>
  <statistics/>
  <xmllogger logDir="D:\Projects\TFS\Main\BuildProcess\logs\ServiceBuilds" />
</publishers>
```