# How to configure Cruise Control.Net to show proper error in Web Dashboard?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, tdd, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

We have setup Cruise Control.Net to build .Net projects from source control. Problem is that when the build fails the error log shows a huge build xml and we struggle to find out the actual error. How to configure Cruise Control to show error in more readable format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that a [xmllogger](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Xml+Log+Publisher) is included in your ccnet configuration and try viewing the build results via ccnet's web dashboard.

[See example of failed build output](http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/server/CCNet%20Live/project/CCNet%201.5/build/log20100610113033.xml/ViewBuildReport.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To make it even more readable (bring the project name along with the error)

in `webdashboard/xsl/msbuild.xsl` add

```
<xsl:if test="parent::target/@name != ''">
            target-><xsl:value-of select="parent::target/@name" />&#160;
        </xsl:if>
```

just above

```
<xsl:if test="@file != ''" >
```

in the `<xsl:template match="error">` section.

so as a whole msbuild.xsl section would be

```
    <xsl:template match="error">
    <div style="color:orangered">
            <xsl:value-of select="./../../@file" />&#160;   
        <xsl:if test="parent::target/@name != ''">
            target-><xsl:value-of select="parent::target/@name" />&#160;
        </xsl:if>   
        <xsl:if test="@file != ''" >
            <xsl:value-of select="@file"/>&#160;(<xsl:value-of select="@line"/>,<xsl:value-of select="@column"/>):&#160;
        </xsl:if>
        error&#160;<xsl:value-of select="@code"/>:&#160;<xsl:value-of select="text()" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```